# hibernate datasource glassfish

Tags: java

Добрый день! Я прочитал и сделал выполнил инструкции как показано [здесь](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-3-hibernate-3-6-oracle-11g-example-xml-mapping/). Теперь нужно этот же пример сделать с помощью glassfish datasource. Что для этого я должен изменит в существующем проекте? Datasource на glassfish admin console уже создал, теперь нужно только вызвать его. Помогите, плз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Конфигурация соединения в Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc) - обратите внимание на таблицу "Hibernate Datasource Properties".  Главное в `hibernate.connection.datasource` указывать JNDI имя.